# Getting error "Root access rejected" in android application

Tags: android

I am getting an error while running this code and the error is " Root access rejected [java.io.IOException] : Error running exec(). Command: [su] Working Directory: null Environment: null"

```
try 
{
    suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
    DataInputStream osRes = new DataInputStream(suProcess.getInputStream());

    if (null != os && null != osRes) 
    {
        // Getting the id of the current user to check if this is root
        os.writeBytes("id\n");
        os.flush();
        String currUid = osRes.readLine();
        boolean exitSu = false;
        if (null == currUid) 
        {
            retval = false;
            exitSu = false;
            Log.d("ROOT", "Can't get root access or denied by user");
        }
        else if (true == currUid.contains("uid=0"))
        {
        retval = true;
        exitSu = true;
        Log.d("ROOT", "Root access granted");
        } 
        else 
        {
        retval = false;
        exitSu = true;
        Log.d("ROOT", "Root access rejected: " + currUid);
        }

        if (exitSu)
        {
           os.writeBytes("exit\n");
           os.flush();
        }
    }
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.d("ROOT", "Root access rejected [" + e.getClass().getName()
                + "] : " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because apps do not have a super user permission in the android system.

Comment: I am trying to implement a code in which i need to compress a video using android but unable to find any relevant API to do that.Could you guide me please?

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all ... you need to get your device rooted. A little [Google Search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+get+my+device+rooted&oq=how+to+get+my+device+rooted) will help with that.

If your application will be running on anonymous client devices, then you should better check first if the device is rooted or not. My library has a root availability check method which looks like below, but it doesn't work in a few cases.

```
    public static boolean hasRoot() {
        String tags = Build.TAGS;
        if ((tags != null) && tags.contains("test-keys"))
            return true;
        try {
            if (new File("/system/app/Superuser.apk").exists())
                return true;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] commands = {
            "/system/xbin/which su",
            "/system/bin/which su",
            "which su"
        };
        for (String command : commands) {
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Then you can proceed with your procedure to execute a superuser shell & check for uid.

Or if you want to simplify things, you can have a look at my open-source Android CLI library with which, this task would be simpler. You can find the github project [here](https://github.com/vaibhavpandeyvpz/rootbox).

Comment: When using this code, it shows "java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/system/xbin/which, su] Working Directory: null Environment: null"

Comment: Most probably you aren't rooted then. Go for rooting first then proceed.

Answer (score 1):

If your phone has root access then you can fire shell scripts using Process and Runtime class..

see the below link:-

[Run a shell command as root on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141235/run-a-shell-command-as-root-on-android)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_%28Android_OS%29

Comment: I am trying to implement a code in which i need to compress a video using android but unable to find any relevant API to do that.Could you guide me please?